# Chart gets clipped when setting height and width

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create a simple line graph using nvd3.js. I got a simple one working which looks like so:

[image: Height/width not set]

When I manually set my height and width, it all gets cut off.

[image: Manually set]

My code looks like so:

```
var min_date = data[0].values[0].x
var max_date = data[0].values[0].x
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([min_date, max_date]);

var width = nv.utils.windowSize().width - 40,
  height = nv.utils.windowSize().height - 40;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    .height(height)
    .width(width)
    ;

  chart.xAxis
    .scale(xScale)
    .axisLabel('Day')
    .tickFormat(function(d){
      return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    })
    .tickValues(data[0].values.map(function(d){
      return d.x;
    }))
    ;

  chart.xScale(d3.time.scale());

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Followers')
    .tickValues(data[0].values.map(function(d){
      return d.y;
    }))
    .ticks(1)
    ;

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

I can't seem to figure out what's going on. Any ideas?

**Update**
Here's a jsfiddle of the top graph, before I try to resize it. http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Jn/1/

Dates can be ignored. They got messed up when I made the fiddle but work fine for me.

Comment: NVD3 should set the height and width correctly itself. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Well, the first picture is just using the default height/width. I'm not setting it there. It too compact for me though. I'd like to make it taller, but then it gets cut off like the second picture.

Comment: It should work like this. Do you have any other elements on the page? Could you post a complete reproducible example please?

Comment: Sure. Here's an example without me trying to resize it. http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Jn/1/

Comment: And another if I change the height: http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Jn/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the dimensions for the chart, you also need to change the dimensions for the enclosing SVG accordingly:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
      .height(800)
// ...
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .attr("height", 800)
    .datum(chartData)
    ...
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Jn/3/).

Comment: Ah, I knew it was going to be something simple like that. Thanks!